# Ошибка при запуске докера: localhost sent an invalid response

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile

**This site can’t provide a secure connection

localhost sent an invalid response.

ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR**
Такая ошибка на странцие браузера по адресу
https://localhost:8080/

Запускаю через docker-compose.
docker-compose.yml выглядит так

```
version: '3.1'                                                                                                    

services:                                                                                                         

  web:                                                                                                            
    build: ${APP_PATH_DOCKER}/web                                                                                 
    environment:                                                                                                  
      APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}                                                               
    volumes:                                                                                                      
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.3
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8060:80

  composer:
    image: composer:2.1.11
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    command: composer install

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Использую убунту.
Пробовал очищать данные браузера, включить/отключать разные настройки хрома. Не помогло.

Comment: Используйте протокол http, т.е. адрес `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло. Читал что браузер перекидывает с **https** на **http** и также исправлял это, не помогло.